# How to set a configuration parameter at DB level in PostgreSQL permanently?

Tags: postgresql

I am aware of the below command:

```
ALTER DATABASE name SET configuration_parameter { TO | = } { value | DEFAULT }
```

On server restart, will these be overwritten by the parameter set in postgresql.conf

Answer (score 1):

The order of settings is like this:

- If there is a user setting, take that.
- If there is a database setting but no user setting, take that.
- Else, take the default setting.

Comment: session - user - database - **system** - postgres.conf

Comment: True. I bundled the last two as "default".

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html

> Set this database's session default for the specified configuration
>   parameter to the given value.

so If configuration_parameter is set for database it overrides the postgres.conf. It should persist after db restart, yes